# Initializing int4 using Swift; bug or expected behaviour?

Tags: swift, simd, swift2, ios9

Playground code:

```
import simd

let test = int4(1,2,3,4) // this works

let x = 1
let test2 = int4(x,2,3,4) // doesn't work (nor does let x: Int = 1)

let y: Int32 = 1
let test3 = int4(y,2,3,4) // works
```

It's clear that `int4` expects `Int32` values, but in the first case it seems able to figure it out without explicitly specifying the type of Int, but in the second case (when the integer is first stored as a separate variable) it doesn't.

**Is this expected behaviour in Swift?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a first glance, this looks like expected behavior.

When you specify

```
let test = int4(1,2,3,4)
```

the integer literals there are implicitly initialized as Int32 types. When you just do a

```
let x = 1
```

x by default has a type of Int. As a safety measure, Swift doesn't do implicit type conversion on integers and floating point types. You would need to explicitly cast it to an Int32 to get this to work:

```
let test2 = int4(Int32(x),2,3,4)
```

which is why your third example works. Rather than relying on type inference to set what `y` is, you give it the Int32 type and the types now align.

Comment: Thanks for the insight :) I think since Swift is capable of type inference (from the first example), I wasn't sure whether that meant it should do it or not in the second case. Makes sense as a safety measure anyway.

Comment: As an aside, what threw me was that the error message said that int4 couldn't be initialised with `(Int,Int,Int,Int)` in the `let test2 = int4(x,2,3,4)` case. If the error message had been that it couldn't be initialised with `(Int,Int32,Int32,Int32)` it would've been a lot easier to figure out what went wrong. It seems like Swift might have used the type of `x` to also infer the type of the other arguments I provided?

Comment: @Matthew - Might be worth filing an enhancement request, with a little test case. I know they keep working to improve the type inference and the errors it reports.

Comment: In my experience the error messages in Swift range from baffling to actively misleading.

Comment: I've learned to treat Swift error messages that don't seem to make sense as saying "Duh, sumptin's wrong here... derp?" All I trust is that *something* is wrong with the line in question, and it's up to me to figure out what.